# Mathcad lookalike for linux?

Tags: linux, math

Sometimes I'd like to make a math notebook on linux, with symbolic equations, text, maybe graphs/visualizations, similar to mathcad documents on windows. Does something like that exist? The closest is GeoGebra, I think.

Comment: Maybe Sage (http://www.sagemath.org/)?

Comment: Sage can display equations decently?

Comment: I’m not that familiar with it, but Sage can do serious math including symbolic algebra and calculus.

Comment: Maybe smith? https://smath.com/wiki/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: And also possibly http://mirai.sourceforge.net/